# How to return the name of a column if its value matches the value of another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame and I want to populate the column "TargetPos" with the name of the column whose value matches that of the column "Item" (so "Left" in this case) (in my actual data, I actually have four positions: TopRight, TopLeft, BottomRight, BottomLeft). What approach can one use?

| Item | Right | Left | TargetPos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bed.png | flag.png | bed.png |  |

I've been trying something along these lines:

```
df$TargetPos <- lapply(df$Item, function(x)
  if (x == df$Right) {
    names(df$Right)
  } else {
    Left
  })
```

Comment: Can you post some reproducible data?

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to have vector as output, you should use `sapply` instead of `lapply`.

The core of the solution is to use `which` to output the column index which has value(s) matching the `Item` column (remember the `+ 1`, since the `Item` column itself is not included when indexing), and output the `colnames`.

I have created some extra rows for demonstration purpose.

#### Input

```
df <- data.frame(Item = c("bed.png", "a", "b", "e", "532523"), 
                 Right = c("flag.png", "a", "c", "e", "aaa"), 
                 Left = c("bed.png", "b", "b", "e", "bbb"))

     Item    Right    Left
1 bed.png flag.png bed.png
2       a        a       b
3       b        c       b
4       e        e       e
5  532523      aaa     bbb
```

#### Code

```
df$TargetPos <- 
  sapply(1:nrow(df), 
         function(x) colnames(df)[which(df[x, -1] == df$Item[x]) + 1])

df
     Item    Right    Left   TargetPos
1 bed.png flag.png bed.png        Left
2       a        a       b       Right
3       b        c       b        Left
4       e        e       e Right, Left
5  532523      aaa     bbb
```

Answer (score 2):

Data from @benson23 (many thanks).
Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(Right, Left), ~case_when(. == Item ~ cur_column(),
                                           TRUE ~ NA_character_), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>% 
  unite(TargetPos, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ', ')
```

```
  Item    Right    Left   TargetPos
1 bed.png flag.png bed.png        Left
2       a        a       b       Right
3       b        c       b        Left
4       e        e       e Right, Left
5  532523      aaa     bbb
```

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, we may also use `apply`

```
df$TargetPos <- apply(df$Item == df[-1], 1, \(x) toString(names(x)[x]))
```

-output

```
> df
     Item    Right    Left   TargetPos
1 bed.png flag.png bed.png        Left
2       a        a       b       Right
3       b        c       b        Left
4       e        e       e Right, Left
5  532523      aaa     bbb
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Item = c("bed.png", "a", "b", "e", "532523"), 
    Right = c("flag.png", "a", "c", "e", "aaa"), Left = c("bed.png", 
    "b", "b", "e", "bbb")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Master I have already asked this but forgotten some how. `\(x)` is the short for anonymous function?

Comment: @TarJae it is for `function(x)` in the newer versions of `R`

Answer (score 0):

You could exploit the vectorization of `==` more. Basically it's `df1$Item == df1[2:5]` gives a boolean matrix then `apply` `which` over `MARGIN=1` i.e. over the rows.

So if your data looks like this

```
df1
#          Item TopRight TopLeft BottomRight  BottomLeft
# 1     bed.png flag.png bed.png   stars.png stripes.png
# 2 stripes.png flag.png bed.png   stars.png stripes.png
# 3     foo.png  foo.png bar.png     baz.png     bam.png
# 4     baz.png  foo.png bar.png     baz.png     bam.png
```

you may do:

```
transform(df1, target=names(df1)[2:5][apply(Item == df1[2:5], 1, which)])
#          Item TopRight TopLeft BottomRight  BottomLeft      target
# 1     bed.png flag.png bed.png   stars.png stripes.png     TopLeft
# 2 stripes.png flag.png bed.png   stars.png stripes.png  BottomLeft
# 3     foo.png  foo.png bar.png     baz.png     bam.png    TopRight
# 4     baz.png  foo.png bar.png     baz.png     bam.png BottomRight
```

If it rather looks like that

```
df2
#          Item TopRight TopLeft BottomRight  BottomLeft
# 1     bed.png flag.png bed.png   stars.png stripes.png
# 2 stripes.png flag.png bed.png   stars.png stripes.png
# 3     foo.png  foo.png bar.png     baz.png     bam.png
# 4     baz.png  foo.png bar.png     baz.png     bam.png
# 5          -1  foo.png bar.png     baz.png     bam.png
# 6          -1       -1      -1          -1          -1
```

you could do:

```
within(df2, {
  target <- Vectorize(toString)(apply(Item == df2[2:5], 1, \(x) 
                                      names(which(x))))
  target <- replace(target, target == "", NA)
})
df2
#          Item TopRight TopLeft BottomRight  BottomLeft                                     target
# 1     bed.png flag.png bed.png   stars.png stripes.png                                    TopLeft
# 2 stripes.png flag.png bed.png   stars.png stripes.png                                 BottomLeft
# 3     foo.png  foo.png bar.png     baz.png     bam.png                                   TopRight
# 4     baz.png  foo.png bar.png     baz.png     bam.png                                BottomRight
# 5          -1  foo.png bar.png     baz.png     bam.png                                       <NA>
# 6          -1       -1      -1          -1          -1 TopRight, TopLeft, BottomRight, BottomLeft
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(Item = c("bed.png", "stripes.png", "foo.png", 
"baz.png"), TopRight = c("flag.png", "flag.png", "foo.png", "foo.png"
), TopLeft = c("bed.png", "bed.png", "bar.png", "bar.png"), BottomRight = c("stars.png", 
"stars.png", "baz.png", "baz.png"), BottomLeft = c("stripes.png", 
"stripes.png", "bam.png", "bam.png")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Item = c("bed.png", "stripes.png", "foo.png", 
"baz.png", "-1", "-1"), TopRight = c("flag.png", "flag.png", 
"foo.png", "foo.png", "foo.png", "-1"), TopLeft = c("bed.png", 
"bed.png", "bar.png", "bar.png", "bar.png", "-1"), BottomRight = c("stars.png", 
"stars.png", "baz.png", "baz.png", "baz.png", "-1"), BottomLeft = c("stripes.png", 
"stripes.png", "bam.png", "bam.png", "bam.png", "-1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```